# System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Equals fails with NullReferenceException in .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, nullreferenceexception, system.reflection

I'm encountering quite a strange behaviour when comparing `MethodBase` instances with `Equals` method using .NET Framework 3.5 - it just fails with `NullReferenceException` in case when comparing compiler-defined constructor method object with open generic method object.

Here is the repro code:

```
class TheClass
{
    public T TheMethod<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctor = typeof(TheClass).GetConstructors().Single();
        var generic = typeof(TheClass).GetMethods().Single(x => x.Name == "TheMethod");

        Console.WriteLine(generic.Name); // TheMethod
        Console.WriteLine(generic.GetType().Name); // RuntimeMethodInfo

        Console.WriteLine(ctor.Name); // .ctor
        Console.WriteLine(ctor.GetType().Name); // RuntimeConstructorInfo

        Console.WriteLine(generic.Equals(ctor)); // throws NullReferenceException
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It works fine in .NET 4.0. 
I've looked into `RuntimeMethodInfo.Equals` implementations in 3.5 and 4.0 using decompiler, here is the interesting part:

**.NET 3.5**

```
if (!this.IsGenericMethod)
    return obj == this;
  RuntimeMethodInfo runtimeMethodInfo = obj as RuntimeMethodInfo;
  if (this.GetMethodHandle().StripMethodInstantiation() != runtimeMethodInfo.GetMethodHandle().StripMethodInstantiation() || runtimeMethodInfo == null || !runtimeMethodInfo.IsGenericMethod)
    return false;
// ...
```

**.NET 4.0**

```
  if (!this.IsGenericMethod)
    return obj == this;
  RuntimeMethodInfo runtimeMethodInfo = obj as RuntimeMethodInfo;
  if ((MethodInfo) runtimeMethodInfo == (MethodInfo) null || !runtimeMethodInfo.IsGenericMethod || RuntimeMethodHandle.StripMethodInstantiation((IRuntimeMethodInfo) this).Value.Value != RuntimeMethodHandle.StripMethodInstantiation((IRuntimeMethodInfo) runtimeMethodInfo).Value.Value)
    return false;
```

In .NET 4.0 the `null`-check was moved before using possibly-null `runtimeMethodInfo` variable. For me, 3.5 behaviour seems to be a framework bug, isn't it?

So the question is - **is there a workaround or a way to compare these objects safely**? Note that in real code I'm not calling `Equals` directly, but using it somewhere implicitly in collections etc., so catching `NullReferenceExceptions` doesn't sound well.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't switch to .NET 4? I know it's not an answer, but it's a solution.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a good workaround, other than writing a replacement `Equals` method. Or at least something that will check the `ctor` value before you call the runtime's `Equals` method. You could create an `EqualityComparer` for your collections, so that it doesn't call the runtime version.

Comment: @ChrisF I don't want to switch as this is more library-like project and I don't want to require .NET 4 from the consumers.

Comment: @JimMischel, you're right, it's easy to bypass the bug with `EqualityComparer`. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there's a good workaround, other than writing a replacement `Equals` method. Or at least something that will check the `ctor` value before you call the runtime's `Equals` method.

For the collection, create an `EqualityComparer` to do custom comparisons. That'll eliminate the call to the default `Equals` method.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented it using just `return x.IsConstructor == y.IsConstructor && x.Equals(y)`. Buggy cases are filtered out by the first condition then.